# To use self. or not.. in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been coding in Ruby for sometime now, but I don't understand when to use:

```
def self.METHOD_NAME
end
```

or just:

```
def METHOD_NAME
end
```

In any Rails model. Is "self" a modifier like private in Java? When should I use it and when not?. Thanks a ton.

Comment: "self" in this context corresponds to "static" in Java. In this case, self is referring to the CLASS (as opposed to the Object). Ruby Classes can also have private and protected declarations. Ruby also uses self as the "this" reference within the OBJECT INSTANCE as well.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
def self.method_name
end
```

defines a class method.

```
def method_name
end
```

defines an instance method.

[This](http://www.rubyfleebie.com/understanding-class-methods-in-ruby/) is a pretty good post on it.

Answer (score 37):

A quick explanation of what that means:

In ruby, you can define methods on a particular object:

```
a = "hello"

def a.informal
  "hi"
end

a.informal
=> "hi"
```

What happens when you do that is that the object a, which is of class `String`, gets its class changed to a "ghost" class, aka metaclass, singleton class or eigenclass. That new class superclass is `String`.

Also, inside class definitions, `self` is set to the class being defined, so

```
class Greeting
  def self.say_hello
    "Hello"
  end
  #is the same as:
  def Greeting.informal
    "hi"
  end
end
```

What happens there is that the object `Greeting`, which is of class `Class`, gets a new metaclass with the new methods, so when you call

```
Greeting.informal
=> "hi"
```

There's no such thing as class methods in ruby, but the semantics are similar.

Answer (score 14):

A good guide on when to use which one:

- If the method depends on any internal state of the object, or must know which instance of the object it is addressing, then DO NOT make it a class (`self.`) method.
- If the method does not depend on the state of the object, or on having a specific instance of the object, then in may be made a class method.

When making a class method, think carefully about which class or module it belongs in.  If you ever catch yourself duplicating code in class methods across classes, factor it into a module that other classes may mix in.

Answer (score 6):

In this context - def self.method_name makes it sort of equivalent to the Java static method:

ruby:

```
class HexHelper
  def self.to_h(num)
    sprintf("%x", num)
  end
end

use: HexHelper.to_h(12345)
```

java:

```
public class HexHelper
{
  public static String toHex(int num)
  {
    return new PrintfFormat("%x").sprintf(num);
  }
}

use: HexHelper.toHex(12345)
```

Answer (score 6):

self is **always** the current object

When you see self here

def self.method_name
end

You are not in an instance method, so self is the current *Class* object.

Answer (score 2):

**self** is like the **this** keyword in Java. It's a reference to the current object instance. If your model code performs an operation on the current object, then you'd probably need a function without self.method_name specifier.