# Invoke action to send email in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, controller

I am attempting to send an email to the present borrower of a book. I've created an ActionMailer called ReturnRequestMailer which has a method called please_return.

```
class ReturnRequestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def please_return(book_loan)
    subject    'Book Return Request'
    recipients book_loan.person.email
    from       'andrew.steele@west.cmu.edu'
    sent_on    Time.now

    body       :book_loan => book_loan
  end
end
```

I am attempting to call this method from an action inside of my BooksController

```
def request_return
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  ReturnRequestMailer.please_return(@book.current_loan)
end
```

Which I invoke from my books index with the following link_to (ignoring for the time being that doing this in this manner probably isn't the smartest permanent solution).

```
<%= link_to 'Request Return', {:action => 'request_return' , :id => book} %>
```

Everything links up correctly but I get a NoMethodError in BooksController#request_return stating that it cannot find the method please_return for ReturnRequestMailer. What is going on that is preventing the please_return method from being visible to the BooksController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a 'deliver_' in front of your method so it will be :

```
def request_return
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  ReturnRequestMailer.deliver_please_return(@book.current_loan)
end
```

You don't need to define 'deliver_please_return' method, The method_missing method in ActionMailer will know to call please_return.

Answer (score 1):

The Mailer in rails is usually used like this:

```
class ReturnRequestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def please_return(book_loan)
    subject    'Book Return Request'
    recipients book_loan.person.email
    from       'andrew.steele@west.cmu.edu'
    sent_on    Time.now

    body       :book_loan => book_loan
  end
end
```

Then in the controller out `deliver_` in front of the method name and call it as a class Method:

```
def request_return
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  NewsletterMailer.deliver_please_return(@book.current_loan)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it looks like the `please_return` method has been called as a class method, but you have defined it as an instance method. (for more detail on this see [To use self. or not.. in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386115/to-use-self-or-not-in-rails/386132#386132) )

```
class ReturnRequestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   def self.please_return(book_loan)
   ...
```

should fix it.

Note this won't actual make it send the email, but will stop the NoMethodFound error.

As [nasmorn states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476572/invoke-action-to-send-email-in-ruby-on-rails/1476625#1476625), you need to call `ReturnRequestMailer.deliver_please_return` to have the mail delivered.