# How to use the "self" keyword in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

Regarding the keyword `self` in Rails, I know that the keyword refers to an instance of the class itself. For example, in `self.encrypted_password`.

I have less of an idea why the attribute `password`, passed as an parameter on the right hand side, isn't prefixed with the `self` keyword too?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible  :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  validates :password, :presence     => true,
                      :confirmation => true,
                      :length       => { :within => 6..40 }

  before_save :encrypt_password

  private

  def encrypt_password
    self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
  end

  def encrypt(string)
    string # Only a temporary implementation!
  end
end
```

Can someone explain when to use, or not use, the `self` keyword?

Comment: Perhaps you can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386115/to-use-self-or-not-in-rails

Comment: @Gran: that's different context :-)

Comment: I missed out attr_accessor and attr_accessible declarations in the above code. so, I have them added accordingly. The thing is the attribute "encrypted_password" is a database field, but "password" is a virtual attribute. it still doesn't seem to make sense for me though.

Comment: @sarunnio: have you read my answer?

Comment: yes, I did, Sergio. thanks for your explanation. but if you look at the above code revised. at the line self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password), I think from its author's meaning, this password attr is referred to the class virtual attribute. but without the prefix "self", the password field is meant to be a local variable somehow, right? as you mentioned below that an instance attribute will be hidden by local variable presence. pls correct me if I understand anything wrong.

Answer (score 8):

#### Answer

The answer is simple: scope visibility.

```
def encrypt_password
  self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
end
```

There is (or, rather, there should be at runtime) *something* called `password`. In your case, it's an attribute from the database. But it also can be a local variable. If such name isn't found, error will be raised.

But you *have* to prefix `encrypted_password` with `self` to explicitly state that you're going to update instance attribute. Otherwise, new local variable `encrypted_password` will be created. Obviously, not the effect you wanted.

#### More explanation

Here's a little snippet of code

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :var

  def bar1
    var = 4
    puts var
    puts self.var
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.var = 3
f.bar1
```

Output

```
4
3
```

So, as we can see, `var` is assigned without `self` keyword and, because of this, now there are two names `var` in the scope: local variable and instance attribute. Instance attribute is hidden by local variable, so if you really want to access it, use `self`.

Comment: So in case of Sarun's question: if there's another local variable `password` in `encrypt_password` function, then I must use 
`self.encrypted_password = encrypt(self.password)` ?

Comment: @user3448806: exactly. But you should avoid this situation at all costs. Brings nothing but confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The question has nothing to do with Rails, but with Ruby. When you look at your code:

```
def encrypt_password
  self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
end
```

it will be translated by Ruby into:

- `self.encrypted_password =` is a method call to `encrypted_password=` method.
- This method is generated by Rails on the fly, because there exists a database column with the same name.
- `encrypt(password)` contains 2 methods calls.

  1. `password` calls the method `password` which is a real attribute of the model by the declaration `attr_accessor :password`. This declaration creates two methods:

     - `password`: getter of the attribute
     - `password=`: setter of the attribute

  See the explanation of @Sergio_Tulentsev how the getter could be hidden by a local variable (which is not the case in your implementation, there is no local variable).

  1. Calls the method `encrypt` with the return value of method call `password`.

So the use of `self.` makes it explicit that you have (all the time) a method call, you don't access the attribute directly. If you want to do that, you have to use `@password = <some value>` inside an instance method, but I like the style with `self.password = <some value>` much more.

I hope it is clear now how your code is interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

**setter method => use self**

Use `self` when you need to **write** something.
In other words, when you need to assign a value.

**getter method => don't use self**

And `without self` when you need to **read** something.
When you need to read a value.

for instance:

```
def write_name(name)
  self.name = name
end

def read_name
  name
end
```

In your case, the virtual attribute `password` isn't prefixed with the `self` keyword because it is *only* read(getter).

`encrypted_password` is what will be stored in the database, it is *written* in the db (setter). Thus the use of `self`.

**Edit**:

Michael HARTL has the same explanation about the very same case:

> (Of course, as we’ve noted, the self is not optional when assigning to an attribute, so we have to write self.encrypted_password in this case.)

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two#sec:an_active_record_callback

(last lines of 7.1.3)

Comment: Sure but it's not the way to do it.

Comment: Because it's painful 5 chars to write when it's useless. There is a lot of literature about self and read/write

Comment: Can you post some links on this matter?

Comment: http://www.amazon.fr/Well-Grounded-Rubyist-David-Black/dp/1933988657/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1326418570&sr=8-1

Comment: http://www.amazon.fr/Refactoring-Ruby-Jay-Fields/dp/0321603508/ref=sr_1_1?s=english-books&ie=UTF8&qid=1326418595&sr=1-1

Comment: Add programming ruby by pragprog, programming ruby by o'reilly and a lot of rails books. Search google also

Comment: @Delba I think he's asking for specific references, not a link to a book. Perhaps page numbers.

Comment: Nah, thanks, don't need to. I was just objecting to your "it's not the way". It **is** *a* way. And yours is another.

Comment: It's not the convention if you prefer. I'm just answering the question of why sometimes `self` is used and sometimes not.

Comment: Delba: well, your answer is misleading (and plain wrong). If you want to write *something*, you don't need `self`.

Comment: Do some research before saying it's *plain wrong*. If you're not willing to read a book (no judgement) or type a google search, here is a short article http://www.themomorohoax.com/2009/05/21/when-to-use-self-in-ruby-rails-models (among others)

Comment: Here's the key: "a. Never use local variables that are the same name as attributes, as that would lead others to, when skimming code, mistake a local variable assignment for an attribute assignment."

Comment: If there *is* a local variable with the same name, you might be surprised. That's cool if you're the only developer on the project and know what you're doing. But real world is different sometimes.

Comment: Are you talking about my placeholder/example code lol?? Come on, you can't be serious... By the way, you can't assign smthg without self. Because you are too proud to admit it, try `class Person; attr_accessor :name; end` Then add some placeholder methods `write_name(name); name = name; end`. You will see... Good night

Comment: Delba: that will reassign parameter value. You're still writing *something*. The wording of your answer is inaccurate. :-) Have you read my answer? I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Obviously you don't. I'm talking about assignment(second line). Stop seeing only what you'd like to see, this ridiculous

Comment: @Delba Maybe you should read more carefully. It's you that's only seeing what you want to see.

Comment: @fgb Someone trolling and pretending with obvious bad faith that I am 'plain wrong', that's what I saw. It's really sad but no hard feelings though