# How to use the Ruby "self" keyword

Tags: ruby, self

I'm having trouble understanding the `self` keyword.

I understand how it's used to distinguish between instance methods and class methods but what about when it's used from inside a method?

Something like:

```
def self.name
  self.name = "TEXT"
end
```

or

```
def name2
  self.name = "TEXT2"
end
```

or

```
class Array
  def iterate!(&code)
    self.each_with_index do |n, i|
      self[i] = code.call(n)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please reference to an explanation here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844703/how-to-use-self-keyword-in-rails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, `self` as a receiver can be omitted, and in such cases, it is usually preferable to do so. However, there are a few cases when omitting `self` make the code mean something else.

- One such case is, as in your example `self.name = ...`, using a setter method. Ruby's syntax is ambiguous between method and variable call, and when  something that can be interpreted either as a variable or a method is followed by `=`, its interpretation as a local variable assignment has priority.
- Another case is when you want to call the method `class`. There is also the keyword `class`, and interpretation of `class` as the keyword has priority over it as the method.
- Still another case is when you want to use the method `[]`. This notation is also used for array literal, and interpretation of it as an array has priority over it as a method.

In each of these cases, you have to make the expression be unamgiguously a method call. One way is to explicitly write the receiver even when it is `self`. The other way is to write `()` after the method.

Regarding your example `self.each_with_index ...`, the `self` can be omitted, and not doing so is not a recommended practice.

Comment: so self is there to remove any ambiguity over where something belongs . Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes, meaning: in principle ambiguous, and when over written by Ruby's preference rule.

Comment: big thanks. (I really  need to get used to how  contextual  ruby is )

Answer (score 3):

`self` has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with the difference between instance methods and class methods. In fact, there *isn't* even a difference between them, because Ruby doesn't *have* class methods. Ruby only has instance methods.

`self` in Ruby is *exactly* the same as `self` (or sometimes called `this`) in every other object-oriented language: it is a reference to the current object. That's all it is. It literally is just a pointer to "myself".

Answer (score 1):

`self` actually defines your scope in Ruby. The scope keeps changing when you switch from module to class, class to method and so on....

Answer (score 0):

Class method (because `self` references to the class):

```
class MyClass
  def self.myMethod
    "hello"
  end
end

MyClass.myMethod
```

Whereas a method without `self` is an instance method:

```
class MyClass
  def myMethod
    "hello"
  end
end

c = MyClass.new
c.hello
```

For variables, it also is a scope thing. If your class has an accessor, you access it with `self`. Not using `self` would usually mean that you want to access a local variable from your method's scope (assuming no magic is given).

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :var

  def myMethod
    self.var # => "hello"
    var # => undefined
  end
end
```

Comment: The OP is asking about `self.name = "TEXT"`, and already understands instance vs class methods.

Comment: Pressed "save" too fast, wasn't finished.

Comment: i've got that , Im asking about the use of self from inside a method.

Comment: when you are using inside the method , self means this method's variable, because you are in the function's scope.