# Why do I need self?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a specific reason I need the `self` in this model's method? I'm accessing it from another controller.

```
  def self.search(query)
    if query
      find(:all, conditions: ['lower(first_name) LIKE ? OR lower(last_name) LIKE ?', "%#{query.downcase}%", "%#{query.downcase}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

Comment: did you try it without  the `self`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ruby, self is used for class methods (as opposed to instance methods), which are equivalent to static methods in other languages.

Example:

```
class Wtf
    def omg
    end
    def self.lol
    end
end

Wtf.new.omg
Wtf.lol
```

Comment: Also see previously asked exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386115/to-use-self-or-not-in-rails?rq=1