# Difference between self.attribute_name and only attribute_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose There is a model User with email attribute.
I have check in some of the tutorials that we can use self.email and email alone. So what is the difference in both ?

Comment: Post some code so that we know what you mean.

Comment: They both are same in a instance method

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386115/to-use-self-or-not-in-rails

All is explained there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access email from different ways when you are on the User class.

- `self.email` when you are in the User scope
- `a_user.email` when you have specified a user
- `email` when you are in the User class. This is valid for every method in the User class.
- `@email`, the variable returned by the `email` function
- `attributes[:email]` the ActiveRecord attribute.

All of this methods are automatically generated by the ActiveRecord model, you can see the doc for more details.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in an instance method within the User model then either will work, but `email` on its own is an implicit scope definition - meaning that the application will look for a local `email` variable, then an email method/attribute. `self.email` explicitly skips the search for a local variable.