# undefined method paypal_url in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a piece of code in Rails,

```
def create
  @registration = Registration.new(registration_params)
  if @registration.save
    redirect_to @registration.paypal_url(registration_path(@registration))
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

I took it from tutorial. But I need just in this line:

```
@registration.paypal_url(registration_path(@registration))
```

Now, about my own controller, `feed_controller`, where

```
def create
  @feed = Feed.new(check_params)
end
```

In the view erb file I put:

```
@feed.paypal_url(feed_path(@feed))
```

In my feed.rb (model):

```
def paypal_url(return_path)
  values = {
    business: "merchant@gotealeaf.com",
    cmd: "_xclick",
    upload: 1,
    return: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}#{return_path}",
    invoice: id,
    amount: course.price,
    item_name: course.name,
    item_number: course.id,
    quantity: '1'
  }
  "#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
end
```

Rake routes:

```
feed GET        /:locale/feed(.:format)                     feed#index
feed#create     POST       /:locale/feed/create(.:format)
feed#new        feed_new GET        /:locale/feed/new(.:format)
feed#destroy    feed_destroy GET        /:locale/feed/destroy(.:format)
feed#edit      feed_edit GET        /:locale/feed/edit(.:format)
feed#update    feed_update GET        /:locale/feed/update(.:format)
```

But it prints the next error:

> undefined method `paypal_url' for <#Feed::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fee24f5fc98>

How can I fix it? What is the problem?

**UPDATE**

```
def index
  @current_user_is = current_user.email
  session[:email] = @current_user_is
  session[:id] = current_user.id

  unless (current_user.member.present?)
    @member = Member.new(:user_id => current_user.id)
    @member.save()
    redirect_to '/feed'
  else
    @new_feed = Feed.new
    @feed = Feed.where(:member_id => current_user.member.id)
    @category = Category.all
    render 'home/uploads'
  end
end
```

Comment: try changing `def paypal_url(return_path)` to `def self.paypal_url(return_path)`

Comment: Could you add the exception's backtrace?

Comment: @TheCha͢mp thanks! But when I print `feed_path(@feed)` it prints me `%23%3CFeed::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fee2ce5db80%3E/feed` why? Can you help me with it?

Comment: I added an answer, also redirecting you to a post about your second issue

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `def self.paypal_url(return_path)` instead of `def paypal_url(return_path)`.

### Explanation

You ran into your problem by defining a `Class Method` instead of an `Instance Method`, there's [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386115/to-use-self-or-not-in-rails) discussing this.

The basic difference is, when defining:

```
def self.get_some_url
  # code to return url of an instance
end
```

you can easily get the desired url of any objects, as in a view:

```
<% @feeds.each do |feed| %>
  <%= feeds.get_some_url %>
<% end %>
```

Now calling `Feed.get_some_url` on the class would make no sense. Which url of the thousands would it call?

But there is a lot of use for `class methods` (where you define the method without `self` as you did)

```
def get_top_5
  # code to return the top 5 most viewed feeds
end
```

Since this has nothing to do with a single instance, you define it for the entire `Class`. Leading to this call: `Feed.get_top_5`, which makes perfectly sense.

---

The **second problem** was not understanding the difference between `where` & `find`, [this post will help you out with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574659/rails-where-vs-find).